P-equitable graph partition
I am now conducting a research in regards to p equitable graph partition problem. I need to use LP techniques to kernelize this problem parametrized by vertex cover. In basic definition of such problem all partition have a size n+-1. but I want to relax the problem and come up with a way to add some vertices to initial graph so that all partition will be of same size. I need a way to add them in such a manner so that if initial graph yielded "yes"(partitioning possible) than its extended by me version will still yield "yes". And same for "no". So far I came to idea that vertices can be added in a way that they duplicate existing edge between two supposable partition, not to break connectivity. But there is no proper proof on my side that this relaxation does not break output of partition.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I want to kernelize p equitable graph partition. The problem statement is as follows: divide graph into p connected partitions of size n+-1. This uncertainty of size really messes up further computation. I want to take my initial input graph G and add to it as many vertices as all partition will be o same size. What i need is: a specific way to add those vertices which won't affect result of partition. Meaning if my initial graph G run through the algorithm gave result "yes partition possible", then G' with added vertices should also result in 'yes'. Same for if partition is impossible
